# Export all collections & subcollections from Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've tried out the [export data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) from Firebase to 'backup' my database but much to my surprise it didn't export the sub-collections, despite them being uniquely named. Is there a way to export the *entire database*?

I know there are [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-export-import) packages that can do this but it doesn't export to the binary format that the GCP exports to which is more space efficient.

EDIT:

I've tried to export the data via the [scheduled cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export) and the [GCP console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import). I followed the instructions exactly and didn't change anything.

They both uploaded a folder with the contents in the images below.

The root directory:
[image]

`all_namespaces/all_kinds`

[image]

I imported the  `2020-11-05T14:40:04_75653.overall_export_metadata` via the GCP console and sure enough all the top level collections and documents came back, but all the sub-collections were not there. I expected that all the collections and subcollections would be restored from the import.

So in summary I tried to export the data via two methods and upload via one.

Here's the scheduled cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();

// Replace BUCKET_NAME
const bucket = 'gs://BUCKET_NAME';

exports.scheduledFirestoreExport = functions.pubsub
                                            .schedule('every 24 hours')
                                            .onRun((context) => {

  const projectId = process.env.GCP_PROJECT || process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT;
  const databaseName = 
    client.databasePath(projectId, '(default)');

  return client.exportDocuments({
    name: databaseName,
    outputUriPrefix: bucket,
    // Leave collectionIds empty to export all collections
    // or set to a list of collection IDs to export,
    // collectionIds: ['users', 'posts']
    collectionIds: []
    })
  .then(responses => {
    const response = responses[0];
    console.log(`Operation Name: ${response['name']}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    throw new Error('Export operation failed');
  });
});
```

So with the above code, I'd expect it to export everything in firestore. For example if I had the sub-collection:

```
orders/{order}/items
```

I'd expect that when I import the data via the GCP console, I get back the sub-collection listed above. However, I only get back the top-level. i.e.

```
orders/{order}
```

Comment: There are three ways to export a Firestore database.  Which ones did you try?  Did you try all three?  Are you asking about one method in particular, and if so, what exactly did you try and what didn't work the way you expect?  Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for your comment, updated the question. Tell me if that helps clear it up!

Comment: Your link to "scheduled cloud function" doesn't go to anything that uses those words.  If you wrote code in a Cloud Function, please share the code here and explain what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Apologies, I updated the link and added the code

Comment: To look into this, can you please provide a screenshot of your data structure? I am not familiar with the ones you provided earlier.

Comment: could you find an answer to this?

Comment: @DiegoGonzálezCruz yes, it's a bit hacky though and I ended up using gsutil instead

Comment: I agree... ended up using the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody needs help with this, I ended up creating a bash script.

```html
#!/bin/bash

# Here we set the project ID for the production environment
PROD_PROJECT_ID="yourproject"

# Now we set the project ID for the development environment
DEV_PROJECT_ID="dev-yourproject"

# Set the Google Cloud Storage bucket name
DESTINY_BUCKET_NAME="db-backups"

# Set the path for the Firestore export
EXPORT_PATH="gs://${DESTINY_BUCKET_NAME}/DATE"

# Authenticate with Google Cloud
gcloud auth login

# Select the production project
gcloud config set project ${PROD_PROJECT_ID}

# Export the Firestore database from the production project
gcloud firestore export ${EXPORT_PATH}

# Change to the development project
gcloud config set project ${DEV_PROJECT_ID}

# Grant Firestore service account access to the bucket
SERVICE_ACCOUNT="YOUR-ACCOUNT"
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}:roles/storage.admin gs://${DESTINY_BUCKET_NAME}

# Wait for a moment to ensure permissions are propagated
sleep 60

# Import the database into the development project
gcloud firestore import ${EXPORT_PATH}

# Optional: Revert the permissions for security purposes
# gsutil iam ch -d serviceAccount:${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}:roles/storage.admin gs://${DESTINY_BUCKET_NAME}
```

Then you make it executable and run it.